# Elementary Set Theory : Are my proofs correct?

Tags: proof-verification, elementary-set-theory

Prove that the arbitrary intersection indexed over the power set is the empty set and that the arbitrary union indexed over the power set is the entire set itself.

$a) \bigcap_{A\in P(X)} A = \varnothing $

$b) \bigcup_{A\in P(X)} A = X $

Where $P(X)$ is the power set of $X$

**Proof:-**

a) Let $x \in \bigcap_{A \in P(X)}A$

Then $\forall A\subseteq X\quad (or\quad \forall A \in P(X)$)

$x \in A    $

Therefore $\bigcap_{A \in P(X)}A \subseteq A \quad (\forall A\in P(X)$)

Now $\varnothing \in P(X)$

Thus $\bigcap_{A \in P(X)}A \subseteq \varnothing$

We know that the empty set is a subset of every set, in particular:

$\varnothing \subseteq \bigcap_{A \in P(X)}A$

Therefore we've demonstrated set inclusion in both directions and by the definition of set equality, it follows that,

$\bigcap_{A \in P(X)}A = \varnothing$.

b) Let $x \in \bigcup_{A \in P(X)}A$

Then

$\exists A \in P(X)  $ such that $x\in A$

and since $A \subseteq X $ it follows that $x \in A$

Therefore $\bigcup_{A \in P(X)}A \subseteq X$

Conversely,  let $x \in X$

Then $\exists A \in P(X)$ such that $ x \in A $

And, so $x \in\bigcup_{A \in P(X)}A$

Therefore we've demonstrated set inclusion in both directions and by the definition of set equality, it follows that,

$\bigcup_{A \in P(X)}A=X$.

Quod Erat Demonstrandum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a) You stated correctly that an element $x$ of the intersection must be an element of every $A\subseteq X$. For $A$ we can take $\varnothing$ so the assumption that $x$ is an element of the intersection leads *directly* to the conclusion that $x\in\varnothing$. This is absurd so you are allowed to reject the assumption. This for every $x\in X$ and the final conclusion is then that the intersection is empty.

b)

> "...and since $A \subseteq X $ it follows that $x \in A$"

I suspect a typo here and that you meant to end this with "...that $x\in X$"

(You stated correctly that - if $x$ is an element of the union - we have $x\in A$ for some $A\subseteq X$. From this you can conlude *directly* that $x\in X$.)

Comment: I was trying to emphasize that any member of the power set of a set is the subset of that set. Is that redundant?

Comment: That is not redundant.